# How to move html adjacent to an element

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML code looking like that:

`text <span> ... </span>. text`

The `span` element can contain html. I would like to use javascript to move the dot before the `span` element and get:

`text. <span> ... </span> text`

How could I do that?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

I think it would make sense to store the text in variables and call JavaScript functions with if statements, etc. Or if you're using something like Angular, which has data binding, it would be easy to display the variable data using conditionals. Alternatively, you could do something like use a template engine like ejs to do if statements.

Comment: ...explanation for the downvote would be nice. I'm just trying to be helpful. Please ask questions if what I'm saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not the one who downvoted your comment. My problem is precisely how to store the text in variables before working on it as it is not contained in an element.

Comment: Well, the suggestion I was trying to make was that perhaps you should be storing the text in variables in a script. Would that be possible for you? If the text were in variables, you could manage things in your code instead of trying to hard-code it.

Comment: Do you mean putting the text between HTML tags? No I can't do it before rendering the page

Comment: Then maybe look into using a template engine like ejs so you can do conditional statements in HTML? http://ejs.co/